# jQuery .show() and .hide() for cloned radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I have a series of radio buttons that were cloned. I wanted to do a simple thing as showing an especific div if the related radio is selected, and hiding if not.  Here's the jQuery function:

```
$clone.find('[id^="mov"]').each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
            $clone.find('[id^="l"]').each(function(){
            if ($(this).is(":checked")){
                $clone.find('[id^="linear"]').each(function(){
                $(this).show();
                });
            } 
            });
            $clone.find('[id^="c"]').each(function(){
            if ($(this).is(":checked")){
                $clone.find('[id^="circular"]').each(function(){
                $(this).show();
                });
            } 
            });
            $clone.find('[id^="r"]').each(function(){
            if ($(this).is(":checked")){
                $clone.find('[id^="rotacional"]').each(function(){
                $(this).show();
                });
            } 
            });
            $clone.find('[id^="m"]').each(function(){
            if ($(this).is(":checked")){
                $clone.find('[id^="mudanca_config_mao"]').each(function(){
                $(this).show();
                });
            }
            }); 
    });
});
```

I managed to show the divs I want, but I can't seem to hide them. When I do the same thing for an else, it won't work and stops showing the div.

```
if ($(this).is(":checked")){
    $clone.find('[id^="linear"]').each(function(){
    $(this).show();
    });
}
else {
    $clone.find('[id^="linear"]').each(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    });
}
```

Also, I know this function is kind of repetitive and messy, so if anyone have a better and clean way of doing it, I'm open to suggestions. I'm new at jQuery and still learning :) Thank you very much!

Comment: Show relevant html. Not clear what is what just from script

Comment: Hey Dominique - a JSFiddle would help as this is a little tricky to read.

Comment: You don't need to use `each()` so much.  Methods like `click`, `show` and `hide` work perfectly fine against jQuery collections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to see what the problem is without seeing your html.  However, you're JavaScript can definitely be tidied up.  The below should be equivalent to the JavaScript in your question.

```
$clone.find('[id^="mov"]').on('click', function(){
    $clone.find('[id^="linear"]').toggle(
        $clone.find('[id^="l"]').is(':checked'));
    $clone.find('[id^="circular"]').toggle(
        $clone.find('[id^="c"]').is(':checked'));
    $clone.find('[id^="rotacional"]').toggle(
        $clone.find('[id^="r"]').is(':checked'));
    $clone.find('[id^="mudanca_config_mao"]').toggle(
        $clone.find('[id^="m"]').is(':checked'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks!! This was exatcly what I wanted to do, and it's a nice way to clean to code! Good to know I don't have to use thousands if .each() :)